# How to animate Position in SpriteBuilder's timeline?

Tags: spritebuilder

The only property I can seem to animate in SpriteBuilder 1.0.4 is Rotation. Is there a way to animation the other properties on the Timeline, such as Position?

---

Edit

Okay, I'm an idiot. I did a tutorial where it said press "R" to add a keyframe. This only adds a rotation keyframe. Option clicking on the Position timeline adds a keyframe to the position timeline.

Comment: Yes, of course. The same way as you did rotation. Perhaps you're missing a keyframe or did not change the position for a keyframe. Hard to say without at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either Option + click on the timeline you want to add keyframes or you can use the built in keyboard shortcuts:

```
Visibility - V
Position - P
Scale - S
Rotation - R
Skew - K
Sprite Frame - F
Opacity - O
Color - C
```

Double clicking on the actual keyframe will bring up the attributes it controls, their current values, and allow you to edit them.